# Using .join() to color all but first column in array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to color all the elements of an array, after the first column. I finally got it to work, however I know there is more "pythonic" way of doing this, and look for some suggestions:

```
for row in board:    
    print row[0] + " " + " ".join(colored(element, element_colors[element])
                                  for element in row[1:])
```

Any suggestions on how to perform this action in a more pythonic manner would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Desired output is as follows:

```
[1] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[2] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[3] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[4] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[5] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[6] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[7] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
[8] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W] [W]
```

Where 1-8 are not colored by the colored function, and all the [W] spaces are.

That way I can keep the elements_color dictionary small:

```
element_colors = {'[X]': 'red', '[H]': 'magenta', '[W]': 'cyan'}
```

Comment: This question isn't really about colouring, or joining, but efficiently transforming all but the first element of a sequence.

Comment: I don't think there's much room for improvement there, apart from passing `.join` a list comprehension instead of a generator expression. I guess you could use `iter` to avoid slicing the `row` list, but that would make the code a little longer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice to transform this in a minimal working verifiable example. I.e. it should include some example input, some output including with why you think that that is correct.

Comment: @PM2Ring well, in this case I woudl use `itertools.islice`, but honestly, usually that just slows things down. And at this scale, memory isn't an issue. (unless row is has a `len` in the millions)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. And I assume this is for some kind of game board, so the list length is probably quite small.

Comment: BTW, Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be using Python 3, unless you need Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Comment: Thanks all! @PM2Ring I know Python 2 is reaching EOL soon, and am working to migrate to Python 3 soon.

Comment: If all you need is print the output to a color aware terminal (i.e. not saving it to a variable) it might be easier to print the data in several chunks, not joining everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to glue them together with `+`

```
' '.join([row[0]] + [colored(e, element_colors[e]) for e in row[1:]])
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it accomplishes the same as others, however is less text.

Answer (score 1):

You could [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the sequence:

```
' '.join([element if index == 0 else colored(element, element_colors[element])
          for index, element in enumerate(row)])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I just did not like having to concatenate the strings, and knew there was a way to combine this in a list comprehension.